# How do you validate a Token is USDC or any specific Token?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, usdc

For my usecase I want to check if msg.value, sent to my smart contract, is actually 10 USDC and not any Shitcoin.
Is this done with the approve function of ERC20 interface? Because right now I have this in my .sol File:

```
require(usdc.approve(msg.sender, msg.value));
```

Answer (score 0):

in most cases there is only one approved USDC contract, so you can easily hard code that for your network inside your own smart contract and not reply on external calls to provide the address unless it's part of your design to do so.

Comment: So it is impossible that there would be fake USDC or fake USDT as the msg.value?

Comment: Or better, how do I check if it is USDC and not Ether which is being transfered?

Comment: msg.value is the amount, it won't have an address in it. there could be fake USDTs, but they are very obvious. token transfers like the one you posted are always for tokens and not ether. ether transfers use different methods.